# How to create (non crud) custom view in rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am m trying to find a way to add custom view ( invoice view ) and add a button in the ( show view ) to print it, any help is appreciated

Comment: I think what you want is a custom action: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

Answer (score 0):

I did this, but i had to create a new controller for my print view.
You don't want to use a custom rails admin action because you'll print page would show the rails admin UI, you could try to hide that UI with some css rules like:

```
@media print {
   …
}
```

But it looks painful to figure out all the elements you need to hide and reflow.
Just create a new controller and link to it from a custom action.
I believe what you want is an action with

```
register_instance_option :collection do
  true
end
```

So your action shows up on your Invoice model, right next to the button "Create new Invoice" and it does not depend on an existing object, if thats what you want.
I offer you a gist with all the files you will need to create an implement.
https://gist.github.com/grillermo/3570369b12e6b4587672f33fc84a8662

Comment: i tried to copy all the files in ur gist without changing anything or any more steps into my application and i got an error
config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::CreateAliadaWorkingHours (NameError)

Comment: You have to rename them, the example action was CreateAliadaWorkingHours so it was configured as create_aliada_working_hours, those are the two words you have to search and replace for your custom action. I asume InvoiceView